# States of an encoder

Tags: coding-theory

Im having troubles coping with encoders in other than controller normal form. Given for example this encoder (i/o is in binary) [image]

It has 2 physical states, because it has one memory and stores u_1+u_2 here (and it`s 0 or 1). Because $v_1 = u_1D + u_2D + u_1$, $v_2 = u_1D + u_2D + u_2$, I would call matrix 
\begin{pmatrix} 1+D & D \\ D & 1+D \end{pmatrix} produces
generator matrix for the code given by the encoder. But the matrix has 4 abstract states (obvious since it looks at $u_1, u_2$ and their past separately) and the controllel normal form has also 4 states (corresponding to separating the branches) and thus is minimal. It is strange for encoder to have less physical states than its generator matrix has abstract states, isnt it?

Comment: I don't think its strange. For example a systematic convolutional code a naturally similarly seems to "remember" too much. The dimension of the abstract state space is equal to the sum of the row degrees only in special cases. For example when the generator matrix is "canonical" (i.e. the gcd of minors is $1$ and the matrix of highest degree coefficients has full rank).

Comment: Anyway, your matrix generates a $(2,2)$-code, i.e. the trivial code. This means that the abstract state space of the code is actually zero-dimensional! You can easily remove all the $D$s from your matrix with a sequence of elementary row operations.

Comment: Recalling a few results from McEliece' chapter on convolutional codes (from *Handbook of Coding Theory*): The McMillan degree of a generator matrix is between its internal and external degrees. Meaning that the degree of the gcd's of full size minors is a lower bound to the number of memory elements in an encoding circuitry, and that the sum of row degrees is an upper bound.

Comment: (cont'd) Furthermore, a polynomial generator matrix has minimal possible McMillan degree (=equal to the dimension of the abstract state space of the code) iff it has both a polynomial and an antipolynomial right inverse. Your matrix only has a polynomial right inverse, so it is not the best possible generator matrix for this code.

Comment: I have problems with relation of an encoder realizing given generator matrix. What it means for an encoder to be minimal? Having same number of physical states equal to abstract states of the matrix? What`s the point when I can have easily less physical states? Or to have number of physical states equal to the dimension of the abstract space? How would we than find minimal encoder for a matrix, whose internal and external degrees doesnt equal?

Comment: Or, applied to the example, minimal encoder for a given matrix should be then just "trivial encoder" sending $u_i$ to $v_i$. But that is encoder for different matrix (identity matrix), which is indeed equivalent to the one given, but still different. When there is $D$ in the matrix, I should see the memory in the encoder corresponding to that $D$. I thought that the encoder is a concept related strictly to the matrix rather than to the code.